# Created a "preview" box to output user's text onto but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple web page that allows a user to enter text and then expect an output of that text in a different format. The user can modify the font, size, color, shadow (light emitting in that regard) of the text that will be outputted after they enter it in the box. I tried to create a simple "preview box" that showcases that output by creating a black box. However, I can't seem to get any output from my code and I am unsure where the problem is exactly.

```js
const fontSelect = document.getElementById("font-select");
const sizeInput = document.getElementById("size-input");
const colorPicker = document.getElementById("color-picker");
const lightToggle = document.getElementById("light-toggle");
const previewText = document.getElementById("preview-text");
const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input");

function updatePreview() {
  const font = fontSelect.value;
  const size = sizeInput.value;
  const color = colorPicker.value;
  const text = textInput.value;

  previewText.style.fontFamily = font;
  previewText.style.fontSize = size + "px";
  previewText.style.color = color;
  previewText.textContent = text;

  if (lightToggle.checked) {
    previewText.classList.add("light-emitting");
  } else {
    previewText.classList.remove("light-emitting");
  }
}

function updateOutput() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("text-input").value;

  // Get the output div element
  var outputText = document.getElementById("outputText");

  // Update the content and style of the output div
  outputText.textContent = inputText;

  if (lightToggle.checked) {
    previewText.classList.add("light-emitting");
  } else {
    previewText.classList.remove("light-emitting");
  }
}

fontSelect.addEventListener("change", updatePreview);
sizeInput.addEventListener("input", updatePreview);
colorPicker.addEventListener("change", updatePreview);
lightToggle.addEventListener("change", updatePreview);
textInput.addEventListener("input", updatePreview);
```

```css
#preview-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

#preview-text {
  color: white;
}

.light-emitting {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
}

#outputText {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="font-select">Select font:</label>
    <select id="font-select">
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
      <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
      <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
      <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
      <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <form>
    <label for="size-input">Select size:</label>
    <input id="size-input" type="range" min="10" max="100" value="50">

    <label for="color-picker">Select color:</label>
    <input id="color-picker" type="color" value="#ff0000">

    <label>
          <input id="light-toggle" type="checkbox">
          Light-emitting
        </label>
  </form>

  <form>
    <label for="text-input">Enter text:</label>
    <input id="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="preview-box">
  <div id="preview-text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. Nice code, by the way. You check all my quality boxes, at a glance. I would just use classes for your CSS to make it reusable. Think reusability with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Nice project.  Seems to work in the editor.  I think maybe you need to change line 15 to a template literal.

```
previewText.style.fontSize = `${size} px`;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals